# Need Hosted Payment Solution (Almost Seamless)

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, gateway

I'm looking for a hosted payment solution that can be made to work almost the same as a seamless payment solution, but I want hosted so I don't need to deal with the PCI compliance requirements.

I am currently using PayPal Website Payments Pro with the iFrame integration, its ok, but the problem is PayPal keeps pushing payments via 'PayPal' and you are unable to remove their stupid 'Pay with PayPal' button from the iFrame. Also there is no ability to customise the look of the content in the iFrame.

I came across CRE Secure's solution which was very clever: http://www.cresecure.com/pages.php?CDpath=3_63&osCsid=eam649uio10ug8igep1kgljgg0, however, they don't support AUD currency.

I would still prefer to use PayPal as my merchant gateway since it saves a lot of money from having a gateway + merchant bank account. For example the CRE Secure solution still hooks up the PayPal Website Payments Pro.

What solutions are there that allows me to have more ability to customise the content in the iFrame and doesn't have any branding of the payment provider, e.g. PayPal etc.

Comment: "You are unable to remove their stupid 'Pay with PayPal' button from the iFrame." - That's not correct. This is definitely possible. "Also there is no ability to customise the look of the content in the iFrame." - There are lots of possibilities to customise the look. Plenty to at least seamlessly integrate it with the look of your site.

Comment: While it may be physically possible, I believe it's against the PayPal terms of service to remove all the extra pay-pal stuff.

Comment: No, it can be turned off from the PayPal side for Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution. However, not all agents may be aware of it. Persist, and you shall succeed.

Comment: McGeek, you can have it removed but as apart of the terms you have to have it elsewhere, which is not what i want. Also you cannot customise the look, try it. I've been developing with PayPal for years, I would know if you could.

Comment: You're right; I stand corrected, it seems you can only adjust the color of the 'Pay now' button in templateD. With templateA, B and C you can customize a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that [Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/) is one of the more popular services that offers these services.

Comment: Authorize.net doesn't offer a hosted / embeddable solution as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks Kibbee, had a look at them, they have some great options, the direct post integration looks like what i'm looking for. They say it is outside the scope of PCI compliance, though i doubt it, but it would significantly cut the costs to get extra compliance since its really just about having SSL on the form page and securing the form from modifications.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I work for Recurly.**

Take a look at our product. We offer a fully hosted solution that you *can* embed on your site (although not recommended). We also offer a feature called Recurly.js (js.recurly.com) that you can fully embed on your site and own the experience, while still maintaining minimal PCI requirements. You can continue using PayPal as your gateway with our solution.

To keep this answer from being total spam (!), I'll also advise you to take a look at Samurai by Fee Fighters and Chargify. Let me know if you have questions, I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Doesn't Recurly only handle recurring payments? Just curious (the name sort of implies that as well).

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at Recurly, was very interested in this transparent POST integration, had a better search about it, and its offered by Authorize.net and some others. I think this is just up my alley. Problem with Recurly is that your solution is really only for US based sellers. There is no way i'm paying more to process my local AUD currency.

Comment: Please note, all the examples above are only for US merchants. I clearly stated, we are Australian Merchant.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer but I don't have the rep to comment.

Just found this is the docs

"This template also offers the following options:
Remove the Pay with PayPal button. Although the form offers the option to pay using
PayPal account by default, you can contact your account manager or customer support to
turn this option off."

So it seems you can remove the paypal button. Can anyone comment as to whether existing paypal  customers will be able to use this gateway?